# Install 32 bit version of libmrm on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit, motif

I am trying to run a 32 bit program on 64 bit Ubuntu 22.04. The program has dependency on the libmrm4 library.

I am trying to install the 32-bit version of the libmrm4 library in 22.04.

I added the 32-bit arch support in ubuntu using

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 sudo apt-get install
> multiarch-support

However when I try to install the 32-bit version of libmrm4, I still get an error:

> apt install libmrm4:i386
>
> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package libmrm4:i386
> ```

Please let me know how I can solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.